# Constructor call must be first statement...error, but it is NOT a constructor

Tags: java, eclipse, constructor

Ok, yet another `Constructor call must be first statement in a constructor` error...the only difference is that I am getting this error in a method that is NOT a constructor...

Below is my code:

```
public DamnEclipse extends Duh {
    private String title;

    private DamnEclipse(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public static DamnEclipse initWithTitle(String title) {
        return this(title); //this is where the error occurs
        // this(title); also gives the same error
    }
}
```

For the record, the private constructor works fine (no errors...). First of all, `initWithTitle(String title)` is NOT a constructor; secondly class `Duh` does not have a constructor specified.

I feel like this is something really stupid either with my knowledge of Java, or just eclipse. Any ideas?

---

UPDATE: I got it working with the following code:

```
public static DamnEclipse initWithTitle(String title) {
    return new DamnEclipse(title);
}
```

But I would still like to know why the one before didn't work!

Comment: `But I would still like to know why the one before didn't work!` Because it isn't valid Java.

Comment: Then I would like to know why it wasn't valid Java...?

Comment: Because that's the way Java was specified.

Comment: @AndyTurner I'm sorry but I was asking what part of my code was not valid Java, merely "that is not valid Java" does not help.

Comment: The part of your code that was not valid Java is the part you've marked "this is where the error occurs".

Comment: yeah, but I mean why? I don't see any part of biziclop's comment help me with the question. Of course I know it's invalid java, it gives me errors! Thanks for your answer btw!

Comment: @JoelMin I have added the relevant snippets of the grammar to my answer.

Comment: Thanks Andy, your previous answer was already sufficient but this is something awesome. Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like @Ramanlfc states:

> `this` keyword is not available in `static` methods

But also, you can't invoke a constructor like `this(title)` from outside a constructor. It's simply invalid Java.

If you want to return a new instance of the containing class, you need to use `new` and the class name, like you would anywhere else to create an instance:

```
return new DamnEclipse(title);
```

---

In case you are wondering why your code is invalid Java, consult the grammar:

```
ConstructorBody:
  { [ExplicitConstructorInvocation] [BlockStatements] }

ExplicitConstructorInvocation:
  [TypeArguments] this ( [ArgumentList] ) ; 
  [TypeArguments] super ( [ArgumentList] ) ; 
  ExpressionName . [TypeArguments] super ( [ArgumentList] ) ; 
  Primary . [TypeArguments] super ( [ArgumentList] ) ;

MethodBody:
  Block 
  ;
```

So, `ConstructorBody` and `MethodBody` are actually two completely different types in the grammar; only `ConstructorBody` contains `ExplicitConstructorInvocation`, and that is what permits you to call `this(something)`. It is simply not syntactically valid to call `this(something)` outside a constructor.

Comment: Thanks mate. So I guess the error message I was receiving from eclipse was not a valid one in the first place?

Comment: But yeah thanks for providing the right answer: `return new DamnEclipse(title);`

Comment: The error message is a bit misleading in your case, but it is still valid. It is true that constructor calls like `this(title)` must be the "first statement in a constructor". And it is also true that `initWithTitle()` is not a constructor. Therefore, it is true that your constructor call was not the "first statement in a constructor".

Answer (score 1):

```
 public static DamnEclipse initWithTitle(String title) {
        return this(title); //this is where the error occurs
        // this(title); also gives the same error
    }
```

`this` keyword is not available in `static` methods

Comment: Hey thanks. But that is not the error I am getting from eclipse. Removing `static` keyword does not solve the problem.

Comment: @JoelMin it didn't solve the problem bcoz `this(title);` call can be made only from a constructor

Answer (score 1):

So when you call a public static function the {this} keyword does not refer to parent class (the DamnEclipse class). {this} keyword not allowed in static context. That's why when you return new DamnEclipse it works. It creates an object.

Comment: You are right, static methods do not guarantee safe reference to parent class. But I am still wondering why Eclipse would complain about the method being a constructor...it should instead say "this keyword not allowed in static context". But yeah, thanks!

Comment: Thanks @JoelMin. Edited my answer.